# Cogs ratio for 1:20 speed increase

Tags: gears, transmission

Question may be a bit stupid and funny, but any kind of help would be appreciated.

I need some kind of a transmission system. I have little to no experience in mechanics or similar, that's why I'm asking for help. I need a transmission system over cogs. I have a servo motor that I programmed to do one (not exactly full rotation, sometimes it's less than one, sometimes more than one. Not by a whole lot) rotation. I have a history in software engineering, but not in mechanical.

I need a transmission with cogs that goes like this: For one rotation of the cog attached to the servo motor, the other cog rotates for 20 revolutions. I don't know if it is possible to calculate or make. If not, are there any alternatives to it? The output rotation shouldn't go below 15 or over 25. Torque is not important, as very little torque is required for this project. Just transmission system, that's it.

Much appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Use ratio of teeth or ratio of diameter.

Comment: A gear is just a round lever. The length of the lever is like the radius of a the gear. Since radius, diameter, and circumference (and by extension number of teeth as long as they are the same pitch) are all linearly proportional to each other ratios of these will all work.

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between the number of the gears and rotation is:

$$\frac{N_1}{N_2}= \frac{R_2}{R_1}$$

Meaning your motor shaft should have 20 times as many teeth as the load gear. So that every turn of it causes the load gear to  turn twenty turns.

A better configuration woud be two stage gears. first stage 1to 5 ratio, second stage 1 to 4 ratio.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. Much appreciated!

Comment: @faris.ibrisevic. if you like the answer please check it as accepted so the other people can use it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem? You need a 1:20 ratio.

Let's say the smallest gear you could get for the output shaft is 10 teeth then you need 200 teeth on the input shaft.

Just be aware that 1:20 is a largish step up and your servo system may struggle to drive it.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. Much appreciated. I thought the numbers would be something like that, you just confirmed it. I didn't take into consideration of servo motor power and torque, you opened my eyes with that. Thank you once again.